# скрыть текст Placeholder при нажатии на UITextField

Tags: ios

Как спрятать текст Placeholder в тот момент, когда происходит нажатие на UITextField, сейчас текст удаляеться с Placeholder тогда, когда начинаешь вводить текст

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Использовать методы `UITextFieldDelegate`:

В `- textFieldDidBeginEditing:` убрать текст из placeholder; в `- textFieldDidEndEditing:` восстановить